# Writing to windows Event Log from within IE extension in Protected Mode - fails with Access Denied

Tags: .net, event-log, bho, protected-mode

In a BHO running within Internet Explorer on Windows 7 with Protected Mode On, I'm trying to write to the windows event log. I'm writing to a source that already exists, and it's in the Application Log so I don't see why this would be blocked. However, my call to `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MySource", "Some message")` fails with an InvalidOperationException, with message "Cannot open log for source 'XXX'. You may not have write access.". The stack trace indicates it's at `EventLog.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)`.

Turning Protected Mode Off makes it work fine.

Any reason this would not be allowed within Protected Mode, and any way I can register my BHO as being allowed to write to the event log, or otherwise make it work?

According to [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/522607-error-writing-event-log#post2042248) the call to OpenForWrite() results in a call to `UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterEventSource(this.machineName, this.sourceName);`, but the docs for that didn't get me any further.

I'm using .net 2.0

thanks.

Cross-posted here: [msdn_microsoft_ieextensiondevelopment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/8befe683-cd46-4446-8571-8569d9d34941)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to write to the system log I would either:

- Create a service and send messages to it - if you will be logging something with any regularity I would do this.  But who writes a bunch of messages to the system log?
- Launch a tiny application silently that is elevated to medium trust as a broker process

Let's go with option two.  A few ways to do this but I will give you one idea.  Write the data to be logged to a file or the registry in a low integrity location.  Then launch a little application elevated to medium trust that picks up the data and writes it.  Is this efficient?  No.  But if writing to the system log is a very rare event then this will yield the least overhead over time.

The service approach will be less obvious to the user but will take a little sliver of pie away from the computer's resources.

See Starting Processes from Protected Mode in [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#upm_undpm).